# What is a word that describes a person's ability to easily express their ideas?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a word which describes one's ability, possibly ease, to express himself and find words that fit in specific context?

Comment: *Literate*, perhaps?

Comment: _Elucidator_, if you want to sound strange.

Comment: Aphasia is a medical condition/term. I would focus more on finding a word that matches the definition given instead of searching for an antonym for a medical term.

Comment: Suffers from [logorrhoea](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/logorrhoea), maybe? Negative, but potentially humorous.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/aphasic

Comment: Aphasia means without speech. Most aphasic people can either comprehend but not successfully produce speech or can produce comprehensible, coherent speech but cannot understand speech. There is no simple antonym for such a condition. I agree with Hank that using *aphasia* is distracting. Please provide an example of context and also describe other words you've considered and why you feel they do not fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Articulate*** -- [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/articulate)

> (adj.) 1. able to express ideas clearly and effectively in speech or writing
> 2. clearly expressed and easily understood
>
> *He had some trouble articulating his thoughts.*

Used as verb also.

Comment: To support my comment above, I think this word fits the requested definition **perfectly** while also not being an exact antonym of Aphasia.

Comment: To support @Hank comment above, I concur. This is exactly what I was looking for. It seems too obvious and a tad shameful, when I think about it now.

Comment: @Reillusion worth an accept, then?

Comment: It's not exactly in common use (and I note that it's flagged "chiefly British" in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/articulacy)), but the specific noun form for *the quality or state of being articulate* is in fact ***articulacy*** (not ***articulation***, which nns in particular might have expected).

Comment: "Articulate" is used in AmE, as is "inarticulate," which is sometimes applied to social interactions rather than writing.

Comment: Fluency also refers to ease in ability in all language skills